# Interference-free integration tests on a build server

Tags: python, docker, testing, integration-testing

I have been facing a problem for several months now where I did not yet find a satisfactory solution to. In the system I am working with, build jobs from various pipelines are all executed on the same build server. The jobs triggered for my codebase include integration tests that require docker containers to be running for databases and things like that, as well as local web servers. On my local machine, this is not an issue, because I can make sure that these things can run. On the build server, that is not the case. Sometimes addresses are already taken or certain write permissions are not given etc. To my knowledge, for languages like Java, managers and frameworks like Maven and Spring help with the low level details of orchestration, so tests like this can run smoothly. For Python, I did not find nicely integrated tools. I messed around with auxiliary modules like `pytest_docker_compose`, but the solution is still too fragile. My  next idea was to just run all tests with their dependencies such as web servers and other docker containers in a dedicated testing-container. But turns out, that also does not look like a good idea upon researching this further.

What is a solid, interference-free solution to run integration tests for Python that require other services to be running on the host? Are there frameworks for Python that take over the orchestration for such a scenario?

Comment: Can you provide more information about how this is failing? Or information about your build server? This is sounds like what Continuous Integration services do, almost by definition.

Comment: It's some Atlassian / Bitbucket pipeline thing. No idea about details, unfortunately.

Comment: Then we're probably not going to be able to help you. We need details.

Comment: Ok, what kind of details would that need to be?

Comment: A failure case is occupied addresses. I could of course write code that works around that, but that feels like a bad solution.

Comment: why not run all tests in containers? I think that is good way to isolate your test env. what you need to do is to manage the ports allocation properly